# Version of Outlook Redemption

Tags: c#, interop, windows-7-x64, outlook-redemption

What version of Redemption should i use if i have:
Windows 7 x64, WinForms App (x64), **Outlook 2010 x86**.

The problem is that Redemption64 5.0 does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 bit. The bitness of you app, MAPI system, and Redemption must all match.

Comment: Can i change bitness of my app to x64 in case of installed ExchangeMapiCdo?